# Metadata Translation API: REST Request URL

Tags: metadata-api, picklist, rest, translation-workbench

I am trying to retrieve the translation for a custom picklist values , using  REST

I think i need to retrieve CustomObjectTranslation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm

I don't see it when i query : /services/metadata/v46.0/components/

I am not able to find the REST request URL to get the translations.

For example,

- i have Contact.PreferedColor__c which is a Custom Picklist.
- I have added translations into the workbench, for french fr and englich en_US.
- I want to query : /services/metadata/v46.0/components/**xxx** and retrieve the translations

What may be **xxx** :) ? Is it available with REST call ?

Thanks for your help